# Visual Studio Replace Regex Replace Multiline

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012

I refactored some code in an class that is used all accros the application.

I want to use built in Visual Studio 2012 Find and Replace using Regex...

Just dont know how to write the regex... On all online regex testing tools, I can do this. However, in VS2012, I cannot get it to work...

The actual code is:

```
_processor.DbTracer.DatabaseTrace(ErrorCodes.DiagnosticSynonymExporterProcessor_SynonymUpdateAffected,
                            String.Format(Resources.DiagnosticSynonymExporterProcessor_SynonymUpdateAffected, updateBulk.Affected, server.ConnectionContext.DatabaseName),
                            CBO.Severity.Information,
                            _processor.DatabaseId);
```

I want the following:

```
_processor.Trace(ErrorCodes.DiagnosticSynonymExporterProcessor_SynonymUpdateAffected,
                            String.Format(Resources.DiagnosticSynonymExporterProcessor_SynonymUpdateAffected, updateBulk.Affected, server.ConnectionContext.DatabaseName),
                            CBO.Severity.Information);
```

So basicaly, it removes the last parameter and changes the method name..

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following regex replacement:

```
_processor\.DbTracer\.DatabaseTrace(\([\s\S\r]*?CBO\.Severity\.Information),[^()]*\);
```

And replace with `_processor.Trace$1);`.

[image]

Just make sure you use `[\s\S\r]*?` to match arbitrary symbol including newline symbols.